# How to access pandas groupby groups in decreasing order of group count in a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I used pandas groupby to group my data using multiple columns. Now, I want to access the groups in a for loop in decreasing order of group-count?

`groups.size().sort_values(ascending = False).head(10)` show me the groups in decreasing order of group-count but I want to access each group as a data frame ( like get_group() returns) in a for loop? How do I do that?

[image: This is how the groups look]

Comment: Can you provide a DataFrame constructor for a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @mozway I have edited the post and added an image.  Maybe that helps?

Comment: Not really (you can't do anything with images), but it's fine, check my answer, I provided myself a dummy minimal example ;)

Answer (score 2):

As hinted in your question, use [`get_group`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': list('ABBCACBBC')})

# assign GroupBy object to variable
g = df.groupby('col', sort=False)

# get desired order of the groups
order = g['col'].size().sort_values(ascending=False).index

for x in order:
    print(f'# group {x}')
    print(g.get_group(x))
```

Output:

```
# group B
  col
1   B
2   B
6   B
7   B
# group C
  col
3   C
5   C
8   C
# group A
  col
0   A
4   A
```

Comment: I'm grouping by multiple columns and `order = g['col'].count().sort_values(ascending=False).index` gives the an error saying sort_values() missing 1 required positional argument: 'by'

Comment: If you use `g['col'].count()`, there should be only one column. Can you try `by='col'` as parameter?

Comment: That gave weird results. I found a workaround though: I used `odvts = list(ODVT.size().sort_values(ascending = False).keys())` to get the groups in descending order and then used `get_group()` to access them in a for-loop.

Comment: @Anwaar you're right. `count` skips the NaN values while `size` counts everything.